# How do daily snapshots in Firebase work?

Tags: backup, firebase, snapshot

How do daily snapshots in Firebase work? Can't seem to find any clear info in the Firebase docs. Can developers access snapshots for disaster recovery and analytics?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-05-private-backups-for-firebase-data.html